# SecKeyAdd returns no error, but can't retrieve the key after the fact

Tags: ios, objective-c, security, encryption, xmppframework

I've been turning my head around trying to get two iPhones to exchange public keys(that are both generated on the devices). The keys are generated ok, and I've tested that I can use them to encrypt data etc. Now my goal is to exchange the keys using XMPP messages, I thus extract my keys and base64 encode them to exchange. The two keys get exchanged and upon receiving them I attempt to save them in the keychain with the following function:

```
- (BOOL)storePublicKeyForContact:(WIMContactDetails *)contact publicKey:(NSString *)publicKey {

OSStatus sanityCheck = noErr;
NSString *contactTagString = contact.buddyFirstName;
contactTagString = [contactTagString stringByAppendingString:contact.buddyFacebookID];
NSLog(@"This is my public key identifier %@", contactTagString);
NSData *contactPublicTag = [NSData dataWithBytes:[contactTagString UTF8String] length:[contact.buddyPublicKeyIdentifier length]];

NSData *publicKeyBits = [NSData dataFromBase64String:publicKey];


//First deleting any existing keys
NSMutableDictionary *thePublicKey = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
[thePublicKey setObject:(__bridge id)kSecClassKey forKey:(__bridge id)kSecClass];
[thePublicKey setObject:(__bridge id)kSecAttrKeyTypeRSA forKey:(__bridge id)kSecAttrKeyType];
[thePublicKey setObject:contactPublicTag forKey:(__bridge id)kSecAttrApplicationTag];
SecItemDelete((CFDictionaryRef)CFBridgingRetain(thePublicKey));



//adding a persistent version of the contact's publickey


[thePublicKey setObject:publicKeyBits forKey:(__bridge id)kSecValueData];
[thePublicKey setObject:(__bridge id)kSecAttrKeyClassPublic forKey:(__bridge id)kSecAttrKeyClass];
[thePublicKey setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] forKey:(__bridge id)kSecAttrCanEncrypt];
[thePublicKey setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] forKey:(__bridge id)kSecReturnPersistentRef];
CFTypeRef persistKey = nil;
sanityCheck = SecItemAdd((CFDictionaryRef) CFBridgingRetain(thePublicKey), (CFTypeRef *)&persistKey);

if (persistKey == nil || ((sanityCheck != noErr) && (sanityCheck != errSecDuplicateItem))) {
    NSLog(@"Error storing key for contact %@", contact.buddyFacebookFullName);
    NSLog(@"Error Code is %ld", sanityCheck);
    return (FALSE);
}

//Now to get the keyReference
SecKeyRef  keyRef = nil;
[thePublicKey removeObjectForKey:(__bridge id)kSecValueData];
[thePublicKey removeObjectForKey:(__bridge id)kSecReturnPersistentRef];
[thePublicKey setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] forKey:(__bridge id)kSecReturnRef];
[thePublicKey setObject:(__bridge id)kSecAttrKeyTypeRSA forKey:(__bridge id)kSecAttrKeyType];
sanityCheck = SecItemCopyMatching((CFDictionaryRef)CFBridgingRetain(thePublicKey), (CFTypeRef *)&keyRef);
if (keyRef == nil) {
    NSLog(@"Stored key for contact %@", contact.buddyFacebookFullName);
    NSLog(@"Error: Could not retrieve stored key!");
}
[contact setBuddyPublicKeyRef:keyRef];
if ([contact getBuddyPublicKeyRef] != nil) {
    NSLog(@"Stored key for contact %@ successfully!!!", contact.buddyFacebookFullName);
}
return(TRUE);
}
```

Now up to the point where I add the key with a PersistentRef the PersistRef is not nil, when I modify my query to get the SecKeyRef using SecItemCopyMatching, the result is nil. At first, I believed that it was a matter of wrong format but how could that be the case since I extract the keyBits(using the functions from the Security Excersice in the Apple docs) and the only change I perform is use the NSData+base64.h library to encode them for the exchange and then decode it before attempting to add.

For further reference heres the method I use to extract the key

```
- (NSString *)getMyPublicKey {
OSStatus sanityCheck = noErr;

NSMutableDictionary * queryPublicKey = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

// Set the public key query dictionary.
[queryPublicKey setObject:(id)CFBridgingRelease(kSecClassKey) forKey:(id)CFBridgingRelease(kSecClass)];
[queryPublicKey setObject:publicTag forKey:(id)CFBridgingRelease(kSecAttrApplicationTag)];
[queryPublicKey setObject:(id)CFBridgingRelease(kSecAttrKeyTypeRSA) forKey:(id)CFBridgingRelease(kSecAttrKeyType)];
[queryPublicKey setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] forKey:(id)CFBridgingRelease(kSecReturnData)];

CFDataRef publicKeyBitsCF;
// Get the key bits.
sanityCheck = SecItemCopyMatching((CFDictionaryRef)CFBridgingRetain(queryPublicKey), (CFTypeRef *)&publicKeyBitsCF);
NSData *publicKeyBits = (__bridge_transfer NSData *)publicKeyBitsCF;
if (sanityCheck != noErr)
{
    publicKeyBits = nil;
}


size_t keySize = SecKeyGetBlockSize([self getMyPublicKeyRef]);
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithBytes:(__bridge const void *)(publicKeyBits) length:keySize];
NSString *publicKey = [data base64EncodedString];
NSLog(@"%@",publicKey);
return publicKey;
}
```

Anyone have any guess as to what I'm missing here, I'm sure its something silly but as I'm new to the Security framework I can't figure it out.

Thank you all in advance :)

Comment: Have you tried looking at the `kSecAttrAccessible` attribute?

Comment: yeah I solved it, it had to do with the format. Apparently the iPhone exports a DER encoded publicKey but its incomplete, and thus it refuses to import it as it expects a full DER ANS.1 key. I'll post a full solution over the weekend.

Comment: Hi, I'm facing the same issue. Could you post how you solved the issue please?